# Wordpress: Strange whitespace under Admin bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, blogs

I'm creating a Wordpress theme from scratch, and so far everything's going well (it's my first time). However, underneath the admin bar I have 18 pixels of whitespace that wasn't in my static HTML page before Wordpress-ing it up. See below for a screenshot:

[image]

The blue part is the header, which should be flush with the admin bar. Is there any obvious reason for this happening?

Comment: Have you had a look with Firebug or similar?

Comment: Sure, from firebug it says the space is being generated above the <body> tag. And in the source I can see: html { margin-top: 28px !important; } and * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }. This is for the admin bar though, and shouldn't be creating the 18px of space underneath the bar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We're short on information here. We need to see your CSS for an accurate answer.

Either way, if you log out, is the margin still there? I'm pretty sure it is. I actually think you're having a margin-top or padding-top on your container/header/whatever element is on top.

If there is no margin, then your CSS is probably interfering with the admin bar. You probably set a margin-bottom on an element that matches either your class, tag or structure of the admin bar.

If you still don't see anything, there is a very slim chance that it could be browser-related. If the other solutions didn't work, try adding a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Firstly I tried the CSS reset, but no luck. Yes the space is still there when logged out, but I definitely don't have any margin-top or padding-top on my container/header etc. The only thing causing this could be the CSS interfering with the admin bar. I'll have a look to see if any of my styles match a class or id in the admin bar. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: EDIT: no luck, no class or id's in the admin bar are in my css. I'll post the CSS file. Here's the CSS: http://dalehumphries.com/so/style.css

Comment: If the space is still there, that means it has nothing to do with the admin bar itself. I'm sorry to go against your word, but I'm pretty positive that your website has a margin or padding in the top element. Is there an online version I can review or something?

Comment: I laughed a little. There are A LOT of errors in your code, but I think I have found your problem. It seems that the browser can not interpret your html properly. Replace `<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->` with `<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>   <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->`. That should fix the problem you're experiencing. I suggest to [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix as many errors as possible because it is truly a mess.

Comment: Looking back on my previous comment I noticed that I havent really explained the problem. The 2 major problems I decided to fix is in your condition tags. Before the closing tag of your last IE condition, you had a comment open (`<!-- `) so I think the browser interpret that as a normal comment and decided not to parse a big part of your HTML. Besides, what if the browser is NOT IE? There are no HTML tags for that. I fixed those two things and I'm positive that's the problem.

Comment: You're completely right, and it fixed the problem. I hadn't even noticed that I'd left out !IE. Thanks so much, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar thing happen, and I believe your issue is white space in your html. Go through and remove any extra spaces which may be rendering, especially before (or after) your     `<?php ?>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could give us some more css. That could have thousands of reasons. If you dont work with firebug or other developer tools you should defenitley check that out. With this tools you can click at the place with the css element you want to see and see the attributes...

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/

or click at chrome on the preferences of the browser...than "tools" and then "developer tools"

If you don't find the answer with this tools, post us some css from your stylesheet

Comment: Firebug didn't give me anything, except that the problem doesn't seem to lay in the <body> of the website. My CSS should be fine as it worked perfectly before wordpress-ing it up. I wouldn't know what CSS to post to be honest, I was hoping that this was a known problem, maybe I should go back a few steps in the development.