# wp admin bar causes whitespace, adding padding causes scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating my first custom WordPress theme. I'm calling `wp_head();` in `header.php` and calling the header in each page. This causes whitespace at the top of the body. To get rid of this, I've added a 1px padding on the top and bottom of my content div. The problem is this causes every page to scroll, whether it has enough content to scroll or not. If you're not logged in, it's a 2px scroll. If you are, it's 2px plus the height of the wp header.

I've tried playing with overflow settings on the body and content divs, but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I also tried setting the content div `position: absolute; overflow: auto`. That fixed it while I was logged out, but added a scroll when I logged into the admin page.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 192, 203); //To highlight any white space.
}
.header {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 1vw;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
.content {
  padding: 1px 0;
  margin-left: 17vw;
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!--header.php-->
  <body>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>  
    <div class="header"></div>
<!--end header.php-->

<!--page.php-->
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="content">
      All the page content goes here.
    <div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
<!--end page.php-->

<!--footer.php-->
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
<!--end footer.php-->
```

I want to have the pages that don't have enough content to warrant a scroll to not scroll while also hiding the wp header whitespace. It's possible that I'm going about things all wrong, so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitespace you're seeing is caused by the WP admin bar _

There are several question / answer combinations on Stack Overflow about this gap

In my WP bespoke themes I don't try to tackle the problem with CSS. I approach it through `functions.php`

```
// remove logged in header bar
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue as well _ But don't forget to remove any CSS you may have added to try dealing with the problem

[This link leads to alternative Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568770/wordpress-strange-whitespace-under-admin-bar) _ Good Luck

Comment: FYI _ There is a Stack Exchange for Wordpress which you may want to think about joining >>> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/  __ Here is another set of solutions on the same problem from that Stack Exchange >>> 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286955/remove-blank-space-where-sidebar-was

Comment: That's the thing, adding the padding was the solution I'd found, but that gave me the scroll problem.

I hadn't thought of hiding admin bar altogether. That would be an easy way around this altogether. Thank you for the idea! Also thank you for the WP community link!

Comment: This worked only if I removed the top margin on the H1 at the top of the content, as the other comment suggested.

Comment: Well Done for finding the solution _ and thanks for the uptick _ Well Done to @Johannes for providing the other half of the solution _ I'm glad it worked out for you : )

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that's due to *collapsed margins*: Although the `.content` DIV doesn't have a top or bottom margin, the margin of the first element inside it (often an `<h1>` element, which has quite large top and bottom margins by default) "sticks out" of the DIV and creates a margin above its parent, the content DIV. Same with the bottom margin and the last child element (which might for example be a `<p>` tag, which also has default margins). So that's what causes the whitespace you describe.

You already found a way to work around that: the 1px padding on the content container. So all you have to add is to add `box-sizing: border-box` to your `.content` DIV, which *includes* the padding in the 100vh `min-height` instead of *adding* it (which causes the scrolling).

Comment: The `box-sizing: border-box` set the height to 100%, not 100vh.

Comment: Your comment about collapsed margins is exactly what fixed it. Once I removed the margin for the H1, it worked, but only if I hid the wp admin bar, as the other comment suggested.